# CSS: No link/hover around image

Tags: css, hover

I have problem with my test site.

TEST Website: http://crafted2.ugu.pl/cn2/

How to make link only on this image ( http://crafted2.ugu.pl/cn2/images/sklep.png ) but no around of it ?
When the cursor is on the right from this image with link, its getting hover..

I am Polish, so my English is bad... (sorry)..

I greet.

Comment: Use `margin-right:270px` instead of `padding-right` in the `.sklep` stlye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin` instead of `padding`.

```
.sklep {
    margin-right: 270px;
    float: right;
}
.sklep:hover {opacity: 0.8;}
```

You do not need to specify the same properties on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin, no padding. Padding will be clickable, margin won't.